# Apache VirtualHosts don't work no matter what

Tags: php, html, apache, markup

## My Problem

I've tried many methods, I've researched a ton of questions on StackOverflow and **none** of them work! Some info:

- I'm running Snow Leopard OS X (10.6.8)
- I'm using XAMPP
- Apache is loading the default (backup) directory. (See bottom of question for what I mean)

---

## Attempt of solving

Here are the websites I've tried:

[Adding VirtualHost fails: Access Forbidden Error 403 (XAMPP) (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110179/adding-virtualhost-fails-access-forbidden-error-403-xampp-windows-7)

[Xampp vhosts do not work (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673192/xampp-vhosts-do-not-work)

[Apache Virtual Host is not working right (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147305/apache-virtual-host-is-not-working-right)

[Apache VirtualHost not working (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653148/symfony2-production-apache-virtualhost-not-working)

[virtual host not working - Apache Web Server forum at WebmasterWorld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3282118.htm)

---

## Additional Info

My VirtualHosts File:

```
<VirtualHost wrks.tk:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Apps/XAMPP/htdocs/DNS"
    ServerName wrks.tk
    ErrorLog "/Logs/wrks.tk-error.log"
    CustomLog "/Logs/wrks.tk-access.log" common
    <Directory "/Apps/XAMPP/htdocs/DNS">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What it's actually loading (This is the defualt directory in the httpd.conf file, the "backup" directory):

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    # XAMPP
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    #AllowOverride None
    # since XAMPP 1.4:
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Which version of Apache? As of 2.2 upwards, by default, you define VirtualHosts in the /Apache2.x/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file rather than the core httpd.conf file **but** you have to ensure that the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` is uncommented in core httpd.conf file. You'll probably also need to add a line that points 'wrks.tk' to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts

Comment: Do you have a line `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in the lampp/etc/httpd.conf?  is it un-commented?

Comment: Version depends on what you use for `Require all granted` >= 2.4 also  Is it not `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `ServerName www.wrks.tk` and `<Directory /Apps/XAMPP/htdocs/DNS>` just looks abit wrong, but im a linux guy

Comment: @LozCherone good point about `<VirtualHost *:80>` - `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` should work too (you have to use `_default_` in some instances, running an SSL server for example on port 443 on a Windows box).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things I'd check are:

Making sure you include the httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Set up hosts:

navigate to Macintosh HD/private/etc/hosts, in a text editor and click Open. Then add this line:

```
127.0.0.1    wrks.tk
```

And maybe try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DNS"
    ServerName wrks.tk
    ErrorLog "/logs/wrks.tk-error_log"
    CustomLog "/logs/wrks.tk-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

You may also want to set up localhost again.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Sorry if some of these paths aren't accurate, you will need to check them against your xamp folder structure.

The simplest implementation I found is this:
http://iwearshorts.com/blog/adding-a-virtual-host-vhost-in-xampp-on-a-mac/

Comment: wrks.tk is a DNS for my IP.

Comment: Okay, so I did what you said, but now I get a "Access Forbidden!" error.

Comment: Check that the file paths are correct, I don't work macs much :/

Comment: Main things are to make sure you include httpd-vhosts.conf and give access via hosts.

Comment: Made some edits to try to make the file paths clearer.

Comment: I figured this out a while ago.  But I'm not realizing that you were correct, that was the problem